# Magento 2 404 error admin panel after update

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel, 404-page, 404

I can't get access to the admin panel after upgrading Magento 2 to 2.1.7.

I get a 404 error on admin URL. I have a CentOS 7 VPS with nginx installed.

I hope someone can help me with this error.

Comment: Check there is .htaccess file is there in magento root folder , also check you all store link working check with any category or product  link

Comment: There is a .htaccess file in the root folder of magento. Any other page is working fine.

Comment: php bin/magento info:adminuri check this command in cmd what is your admin url.

Comment: I get this /admin_18qeho. If I do domain.com/admin_18qeho I get also 404 error.

Comment: this issue have lot of reason. 1) sudo a2enmod rewrite enable 2)  /var/www/ AllowOverride All 3) try php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and check

Comment: Get the messages sudo: a2enmod: command not found and /var/www/: Is a directory.

Comment: your apache check mod_rewrite is enable. also check apache configuration  AllowOverride All. both are apache configuration.

Comment: did you checked mod_rewrite is enable?

Comment: Can't get into apache configuration because of cPanel. I can't find anything in FTP about apache configuration.

Comment: Please check that may be the problem for that. please check and let me know

Comment: I edit the conf file via WHM and when I'm loading the admin URL it keeps loading. edit: gives also 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You can check on your codebase.
app/etc/env.php
 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin',
  ),
......
In this case "admin" is my admin url.
You can check this and change in your mind.